# PHP Error - Can't Open Files

Tags: php, header, include, warnings

I am building a small PHP system, and I can't open files like CSS Styles, PHP Include function and Images.

I also got some errors:

```
Warning: include(includes/functions.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/chezki/public_html/XXX.XXX/cp/CMS/index.php on line 2

Warning: include(includes/functions.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/chezki/public_html/XXX.XXX/cp/CMS/index.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/chezki/public_html/XXX.XXX/cp/CMS/index.php on line 2

Built by YYY.YYY
logo  // Thats the Logo alt

Fatal error: Call to undefined function getlists() in /home/chezki/public_html/XXX.XXX/cp/CMS/index.php on line 28
Title   Actions  // Some images alt
```

Edit: On Windows, It is Ok, but on Linux, It is doing those errors
More edit: Solved

Comment: What do you think that *No such file or directory* means?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `./` (stands for “current directory”) in front of your inclusion path?

Comment: @anroesti: not necessary. the include_path already includes `.`

Comment: I said it works on windows. YES!

Comment: @NoamLahmi just because it works in one environment doesn't mean you can simply slap it into another and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

From your error messages, your script appears to be this:

```
/home/chezki/public_html/XXX.XXX/cp/CMS/index.php
```

Your are trying to load this file:

```
includes/functions.php
```

Since you get this error message:

> No such file or directory

... the obvious conclusion is that this file does not exist:

```
/home/chezki/public_html/XXX.XXX/cp/CMS/includes/functions.php
```

Feel free to edit your question and provide more details if this is not the case.

**Edit:** the file must have that precise name. If it's called e.g. `Functions.php`, it's a different file.

Comment: I Used the exact Files names **Fix** Its seems to be a Upper Lower case Problam

Comment: @NoamLahmi - That's what I say in my edit. If it uses a different case, it's a different file.

Answer (score -1):

You have permission problems. Your web server cannot read functions.php due to wrong permissions. Adjust permissions with chown and chmod.

Comment: -1. if it was permissions, it'd be "permission denied", not "no such file".